# How to use setInterval and clearInterval for infinite gallery

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I am trying to fetch pictures for a gallery using JavaScript, but I experience problems.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var currentPage = 1;
    var totalPics = 2;
    var picPerPage = 1;
    intervalID = window.setInterval(function() {
          console.log(currentPage*picPerPage);
          if (totalPics > (currentPage*picPerPage)) {
        currentPage++;
        fetchNextPage(currentPage);
          } else {
        clearInterval(intervalID);
          }


    }, 2000);


});
```

For some reason, it will keeping looping. I want it to stop the moment `currentPage * picPerPage > totalPics`.

**i am using firefox 3.6.8 in ubuntu**

**update**

Thank you guys.

i realise that the issue is due to the fetchNextPage() function.

oncei commented it out, the looping issue is resolved.

however, i need the fetchNextPage function to run a ajax function to fetch  another set of images.

below is the function

```
function fetchNextPage(currentPage) {

    newUrl = currentUrl + currentPage;

    $.ajax({
        url: newUrl ,
        success: function(data) {
            // append page 2 themes
            $('#themes-list').append(data);

        }
    });
}
```

so what should i do so that my infinite gallery can work?

Thank you.

Comment: What's the output on your console? Does `currentPage` get incremented?

Comment: its incremented to 2. after that console.log keeps churning out 2 every 2 seconds.

Comment: Can you specify which browser you're using?

Comment: i am using firefox 3.6.8 in ubuntu

Comment: Your code seems fine: http://jsfiddle.net/MedP9/

Comment: What happens when you execute this in the Firebug console environment? It works fine for me...

Comment: i realise that the ajax caused the issue in the infinite loop. what should i do so that my primary objective is fulfilled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me. I put in console.log() instead of the function and did not correct `intervalID` not properly defined. Is it possible the function alters values?

```
var currentPage = 1;
var totalPics   = 2;
var picPerPage  = 1;

intervalID = window.setInterval(function() {

    console.log("A", currentPage*picPerPage);

    if (totalPics > (currentPage*picPerPage)) {
        currentPage++;
        console.log("B", currentPage);
    } else {
        console.log("C All Done");
        clearInterval(intervalID);
    }

}, 2000);
```

The output I got (Chrome 5.0.375.127 on OSX):

```
A 1
B 2
A 2
C All Done
```

**UPDATE**: So with your added code I have a few questions and comments:

```
function fetchNextPage(currentPage) {
    var newUrl = currentUrl + currentPage; // Added var declaration here. 
    $.ajax({
        url: newUrl ,
        success: function(data) {
            // append page 2 themes
            $('#themes-list').append(data);
        }
    });
}
```

So whats missing here is the data that comes back... can you provide an example of what value `data` is?

Comment: hi michael, thanks for reply. yea, my fetchNextPage function is affecting something. though i am nto sure how. i have updated my question. please advise. :)

Comment: Oh it works now.
I accidentally fetch the WHOLE page again in the data instead of just a bunch of li elements.

thanks michael. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `var` before `intervalID = window.setInterval` to correctly define the intervalID  variable.

Answer (score 0):

Alex's answer alluded to a possible problem.

This code works just fine in a test environment where there is no other code anywhere.

However, `intervalID` is defined as a global variable. If you have code executing elsewhere that also defines a value for `intervalID`, then it's going to be stomping all over this one.

Use `var intervalID` to limit the scope of this variable.